# Pyspark - How to filter out .gz files based on regex pattern in filename when reading into a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a folder structure as following:
data/level1=x/level2=y/level3=z/

And in this folder, I have some files as following:
filename_type_20201212.gz
filename_type_20201213.gz
filename_pq_type_20201213.gz

How do I read only the files with prefix "filename_type" into a dataframe?

There are many level1,level2,level3 subfolders. So, the data/ folder has to be loaded into a pyspark dataframe while reading files that have the above file name prefix.